# Fujita decomposition versus Zariski decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds, stability

***Fujita decomposition***: Let $\frak \pi : X \to B$ be a fibration of a compact Kahler manifold $\frak X$ over a projective curve $\frak B$ then $\pi_*\left(K_{\frak X/B}\right)=A\oplus B$  where $A$ is an ample vector bundle and $B$ is a unitary flat bundle.

Now take $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on $\frak X$ then is there any such decomposition for

$$K_{\frak B}\otimes \pi_*( K_{ \frak X/B}+E)^{**}=\mathbb A\oplus \mathbb B$$

where $\mathbb A$ is semi-ample vecotr bundle and $\mathbb B$ is effective bundle

Note that A vector bundle $E$ on a compact complex manifold $X$ is said to be semi-ample if for some positive integer $k$, its symmetric power $S^kE=f_*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P E}(k)$ is generated by its global section.

My conjecture is that if $E$ be $\pi$-stable vecotr bundle then we have such Fujita type decomposition.

Comment: In fact existence of initial Hermitian metric for Donaldson flow along such holomorphic fibre space to give relative Hermitian Einstein metric correspond to existence of such decomposition.